# Linq extension method equivalent for that code in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

**Well**, I want to know if there is a way to get the same result with that code:

```
For Each win As Window In Application.Current.Windows
    If win.GetType() = GetType(MainWindow) Then
       Return win
    End If
Next
```

I tried using, .Where method, but it's only disponible por IEnumerable interfaces... I tried to cast it with .Cast(Of ...), but I don't know which type I have to use...

So, can somebody help me with this?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Return Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of MainWindow)().FirstOrDefault()
```

It will return `Nothing` if no matching item is found. You can assign `FirstOrDefault()` result to variable and return it if it's not `Nothing` only to fully match your current code.

```
Dim mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of MainWindow)().FirstOrDefault()
If mainWindow IsNot Nothing Then
    Return mainWindow
End If
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm trying to find! :D